# Batch file to ping some IPs and return lowest ping

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file to test ping of multiple servers and return the lowest ping.
I've already tested this code but the batch file don't run on Servers. I think its because of `findstr`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem Initialize variables
set "selected="
set "min=99999999"
set serverList= "188.165.254.85" "94.23.206.130" "176.31.117.82" "37.59.51.212" "188.165.214.76" "37.59.56.102" "94.23.8.105"

echo - Pinging ...

rem Enumerate the hosts to check
for %%a in ( %serverList% ) do (

    rem Ping the host and retrieve the average roundtrip
    for /f "tokens=6 delims== " %%r in ('
        ping -n 1 "%%~a" ^| findstr /r /c:"^  .*ms$"
    ') do for /f "delims=ms" %%t in ("%%r") do (
        echo "%%~a" : %%t ms

        rem Determine if the current host has a lower rtt
        rem if %%t geq min or min is already 0, then we have
        rem a division by 0, else a lower rtt has been found
        set /a "1/(min/(%%t+1))" && (
            set "selected=%%~a"
            set "min=%%t"
        )
        rem Of course this can be done with delayed expansion,
        rem just a question of personal preferences
    )
) 2>nul

echo(
echo - Selected ...
echo %selected% : %min%
pause
```

Comment: *"the batch file don't run on Servers."*  Why not?  Are you getting a **command-not-found error**?  Or an **insufficient permssions** error? or some other problem?

Comment: cmd will not respond and after that it says findstr error or something like that I cant remember.

Comment: I'd highly recommend finding out the text of the error and getting back to us.